# Using sfrac with normal font size

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I want to use the `\sfrac` command from the `xfrac` package, but I want the font size in nominator in denominator to be normal, not smaller. I read the accompanying [PDF for xfrac](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfrac.pdf) but do not understand how to do it. Can someone help?

As an example:

[image]

I would like the text (1.4 and 1+...) to be right where they are (slightly heigher, slightly lower), but with the same font size as 0.1.

Comment: Please can you add a picture of the exact measure you want? The package you use has those measures. You could use `\tfrac` for example.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Does this suffice?

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not help you.
The `memoir` class offers several ways to typeset fractions among which are the `\slashfracstyle` macro for setting the font and the `\slashfrac` macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfracstyle}[1]{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont #1}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfrac}[2]{\leavevmode
  \raise.5ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#1}}\kern-.13em/%
  \kern-.15em\lower.25ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Fractions can be typeset like 3/4 or $\frac{3}{4}$ or \slashfrac{3}{4}
or \slashfracstyle{3/4}.
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Perhaps you could use these macros in your work.